# Pass variables to python script included using exec(open().read())

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, include, exec

I'm getting an error while trying to access a variable from a function which is included using `exec(open().read())`.

But here I'm able to access the function `printName()`. Is there any other way without using `subprocess`?

I'm using python 3.7

main.py

```
age = 32
def printName(name):
    print(name)
exec(open("action.py").read())
```

action.py

```
printName("John")
print(age)
```

> John
>
> NameError: name age is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code you are mentioned is working I think you are running `action.py` technically you need to run the `main.py` file that contained this code.

```
age = 32
def printName(name):
    print(name)
exec(open("action.py").read())
```

[image]